# Catch the START button of youtube player and the seconds of view

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, youtube

I searched a lot a way to get the seconds of a video view for a user thet visit my site. The videopage have embed youtube videos and I need the number of seconds view for posting on facebook. Rules said:

> If the person watches more than 50% of a video, but does not complete
>   it, the action instance should be updated to reflect that the person
>   has stopped watching by updating expires_in to the length of time the
>   video was actually watched from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.watches/

So far I have the following code where I improvised. When user press start video I start a counter. The problems are in the code comments.

```
function stopCycle(event) {
    switch( event.data ) {
//event.data can be 1 or 2 . If user press play is event.data = 1 and if press
pause event.data = 2 and again if press play will be case 1. So each time
when user press START - PAUSE - CONTINUE - PAUSE event.data will have the value
        case 1:
// here i post on facebook after 10 seconds as rules said
            setTimeout('postwatch()', 10000);


//i get with ajax from youtube the video time (in seconds)
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tj_video_id_url', TRUE); ?>?alt=json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
//here I appeal the ontimer function but the bug is that every tine i press play button even and after pause get appeal and the counter got crazy
                onTimer(data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds);
            }
            });

        break;
        }
            console.log("onStateChange has fired!\nNew state:" );

}

i = 0;
function onTimer(videotime) {
  document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
  i++;
  if (i > videotime) {
    alert('Finish!');
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
  }
}
```

Do you know any alternative or can answer me a correct method for me?

Answer (score 0):

I made this as alternative but i have some delay, when i click pause video, the timer stop but when i press play the timer already start with + 1 second but in video i may pause on second 4,5 and my timer go from 5:

```
    var started = 0;
    function stopCycle(event) {
        switch( event.data ) {
            case 1:
            ispaused = false;
            if(started == 0) {
                setTimeout('postwatch()', 10000);
                onTimer(youtube.youtubeinfo.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds, 0);
                started = 1;
            }else if(started == 1) {
                onTimer(youtube.youtubeinfo.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds, i);
            }

            break;
            case 2:
                setPause();
                console.log('pauz');
            break;
            }
    }

var ispaused=false;
function setPause(){
   ispaused=!ispaused;
}

i = 0;
function onTimer(videotime, remaining) {
if(!ispaused) {
  document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
  if(remaining > 0) {
        i = remaining;
        console.log('ramas');
    }

  console.log(i);
  if (i > videotime) {
    alert('Finish!');
  }else{
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
  }
    i++;
}
}
```